# Are ECR Lifecycle Tasks tag prefix matches case-sensitive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr, docker-tag

If I have a lifecycle policy on my AWS ECR. Are those tasks case-sensitive?
As an example, say I were to have the following policy:

```
{
      "action": {
        "type": "expire"
      },
      "selection": {
        "countType": "sinceImagePushed",
        "countUnit": "days",
        "countNumber": 15,
        "tagStatus": "tagged",
        "tagPrefixList": [
          "ABCD-"
        ]
      },
      "description": "Expire ABCD images older than 15 days",
      "rulePriority": 3
    }
```

Now if I have two images which are older than 15 days in my registry tagged

```
abcd-1.0.0
ABCD-1.1.1
```

Would it expire both of these images, or just `ABCD-1.1.1`?

Comment: Yeah those are not the same as AWS Resource Tags.  I did post a new answer see below thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker tags are case sensitive:

> A quick post about pulling docker containers (this applies to docker run too)…when specifying the container image, the container image name and tag are case sensitive. We’re not going to discuss how much time troubleshooting it too me to figure this out…but let’s just say it’s more than I care to admit publicly.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/docker-image-tags-are-case-sensitive